# Convert java code contain generic to scala

Tags: java, scala, generics

I tried to convert some javaFX default sample that is how to using `TableCellFactory`. In that sample there are some generic (with question mark). I try to convert that code with eclipse default converter that is this code:

```
this.invited.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
        System.out.println(firstNameProperty().get() + " invited: " + t1);
    }
});
```

become this:

```
this.invited.addListener(new ChangeListener[Boolean]() {

  def changed(ov: ObservableValue[_ <: Boolean], t: java.lang.Boolean, t1: java.lang.Boolean) {
    println(firstNameProperty().get + " invited: " + t1)
  }

})
```

With error output:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it should be a `new ChangeListener[java.lang.Boolean]` and `ov: ObservableValue[_ <: java.lang.Boolean]` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Per [serejja's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500125/convert-java-code-contain-generic-to-scala#comment34231690_22500125): Use the fully-qualified `java.lang.Boolean` in the type parameters:

```
this.invited.addListener(new ChangeListener[java.lang.Boolean]() {
  def changed(ov: ObservableValue[_ <: java.lang.Boolean], t: java.lang.Boolean, t1: java.lang.Boolean) {
    println(firstNameProperty().get + " invited: " + t1)
  }
})
```